# Sql Script Leave Dates Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table employeeLeaveDetails

| AppNo(PK) | EmpCode | LeaveFrom | LeaveTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/09/2022 | 03/09/2022 |
| 2 | A | 05/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 |
| 3 | A | 07/09/2022 | 08/09/2022 |
| 4 | A | 12/09/2022 | 15/09/2022 |

If an Employee took leave from 01/09/2022 to 03/09/2022, after they comes back, taken another leave from 05/09/2022 to 06/09/2022, instead of come back on duty on 07/09/2022, they've extended leave for 2 days. means, this leave from 05/09/2022 - 08/09/2022

Result I am looking like below

| Empcode | LeaveFrom | LeaveTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/09/2022 | 03/09/2022 |
| A | 05/09/2022 | 08/09/2022 |
| A | 12/09/2022 | 15/09/2022 |

Application No: 2 & 3 Extended Leave ( Leave to + 1 day = next leave from)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query.

```
SELECT 
E1.empcode,
E1.LeaveFrom,
ISNULL(E2.LeaveTo,E1.LeaveTo) AS LeaveTo
FROM employeeLeaveDetails E1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
employeeLeaveDetails E2 ON DATEADD(DAY,1,E1.LeaveTo)=E2.LeaveFrom AND E1.empcode=E2.empcode
WHERE E1.AppNo(PK) NOT IN (SELECT  ISNULL(EE2.AppNo(PK),'') FROM employeeLeaveDetails EE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
employeeLeaveDetails EE2 ON DATEADD(DAY,1,EE1.LeaveTo)=EE2.LeaveFrom AND E1.empcode=E2.empcode)
```

Comment: APPNO App_Date EmpCode Leave From Leave To
30942 06-09-2022 S1225 10-09-2022 20-09-2022
31071 14-09-2022 S1225 22-09-2022 25-09-2022
31208 25-09-2022 S1225 26-09-2022 27-09-2022
31323 04-10-2022 S1225 06-10-2022 08-10-2022
    
Result Want    
   
Attendance Status   
09-09-2022 P
10-09-2022 L
11-09-2022 L
12-09-2022 L
13-09-2022 L
14-09-2022 L
15-09-2022 L
16-09-2022 L
17-09-2022 L
18-09-2022 L
19-09-2022 L
20-09-2022 L
21-09-2022 A
22-09-2022 L
23-09-2022 L
24-09-2022 L
25-09-2022 L
26-09-2022 L
27-09-2022 L

Answer (score 0):

```
select   EmpCode
        ,min(LeaveFrom) as LeaveFrom
        ,LeaveTo
from     (
         select EmpCode
               ,LeaveFrom
               ,case when datediff(day, LeaveTo, lead(LeaveFrom) over(partition by EmpCode order by LeaveFrom)) <= 1 then lead(LeaveTo) over(partition by EmpCode order by LeaveFrom) else LeaveTo end as LeaveTo
         from   t
         ) t
group by EmpCode, LeaveTo
```

| EmpCode | LeaveFrom | LeaveTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-03 |
| A | 2022-09-05 | 2022-09-08 |
| A | 2022-09-12 | 2022-09-15 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hzjNJNhk)

Comment: Thank you Mr.DannySlor, this is right answer.